# How to pass redirect_uri in next-auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I do authorization via next-auth

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        {
            id: 'reddit',
            name: 'Reddit',
            clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
            scope: 'read submit identity',
            type: 'oauth',
            version: '2.0',
            params: { grant_type: 'authorization_code' },
            accessTokenUrl: ' https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token',
            authorizationUrl: 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?response_type=code&duration=permanent',
            profileUrl: 'https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me',
            profile: profile => {
                return {
                    id: profile.id as string,
                    name: profile.name,
                    email: null,
                };
            },
        },
    ],
});
```

And I am getting error from reddit
/you sent an invalid request

- invalid redirect_uri parameter./

How am I supposed to pass this uri in next-auth?

NEXTAUTH_URL variable is also specified

This is how next-auth inserts it into Request URL

```
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Freddit
```

but I just need

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it) u just need to set redirect_uri in your reddit app as

```
http://localhost:8080/api/auth/callback/reddit
```

Comment: Where did you put it?

Comment: Add the redirect_uri in https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps/ @kodfire